# Linear Algebra : Positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

For the case of a real, symmetric, $n \times  n$ matrix $A$,

If A is positive definite, it may be written in the form $A=PP'$, where $P$ is $n\times n$.

How can I prove this?

Comment: What is $'$? Transposition? And then I assume you want to have your positive definite matrices symmetric?

Comment: Yes ′ means Transposition.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I know all of the eigenvalue of the positive definite matrices are positive number. but I can't prove that..

Comment: @martini I have always thought that positive definite matrices need to be symmetric. But, I might be mistaken. So, do you know a place where they don't assume this while developing the theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is Hermitian, then it can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix $U$ such that:
$$
A=UDU^*
$$ 
where $U^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $U$. Now because $A$ is positive definite, all its eigenvalues are positive and hence $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal and we can write:
$$
D=D^{1/2}D^{1/2}\implies A=UD^{1/2}D^{1/2}U^*=(UD^{1/2})(UD^{1/2})^*.
$$
Now it is enough to see that $A$ is real symmetric and hence $U^*=U'$.

---

For a more specific results on the topic look at [Cholesky Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Answer (score 1):

Just verify that you can always do a [Cholesky factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky_algorithm). The algorithm is also a proof of it.

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric matrices are diagonalizable by orthogonal transformations, let $S$ diagonalize $A$ with $D$ diagonal: $$A=S^TDS=S^T(\sqrt{D})^T\sqrt{D}S=(\sqrt{D}S)^T\sqrt{D}S=P^TP$$